# Bash parameter expansion - greedy versus non-greedy

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

It's a bit of a contrived example but here goes:
Say I have a variable `1.2.3.4` containing version information and need to replace the `.4` at the end with `.5`

```
version=1.2.3.4
echo ${version%.*}.5
1.2.3.5    #no problem
```

But when I attempt to "in-line" the substitution with `/` and a `%` anchor

```
echo ${version/%.*/.5}
1.5
```

Bash does a greedy substitution. Is there a way to have bash take the substitution up "non-greedily" so I can use substitution as a replacement for the earlier delete+append approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in general but easily in this case:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo ${version/%+([0-9])/}
1.2.3.
```

Comment: Dankeschön, works in the simple case. I am going to have to learn to live without it for the more complex cases

Answer (score 5):

I think you can not `non-greedy` in `search and replace`, you can only do it with substring removal. From bash references:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. **Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern
>   against its value is replaced with string**. If pattern begins with ‘/’,
>   all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the
>   first match is replaced. If pattern begins with ‘#’, it must match at
>   the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins
>   with ‘%’, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.
>   If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following
>   pattern may be omitted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution operation is applied to
>   each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
>   list.

To solved this, you should set `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' "${version/%.+([0-9])/.5}"
1.2.3.5
```

or use some tools like `sed` or `perl`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$version" | perl -pe 's/\.\d+$/\.5/'
1.2.3.5
```

Comment: gnouc, much appreciate the detailed response and +1. Accepted Hauke's on a first-past-the-post basis